# PHP call_user_func on a static method

Tags: php, symfony, runtime

I am developing on Symfony2 and I need to call a method on a class, both known only at runtime.

I have already successfully used [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) in the project, but this time they give me problems...

My code looks like this

```
namespace MyBundleNamespace;

use MyBundle\Some\Class;

class MyClass
{
    public static function myFunction() { ... }
}
```

and in some other file I need to do this

```
MyClass::myFunction();
```

but dynamically, so I tried both

```
$class = "MyClass";
$method = "myFunction";

$class::$method();
```

and

```
$class = "MyClass";
$method = "myFunction";
call_user_func("$class::$method");
```

But I get a `class MyClass not found` error. Of course the class is included correctly with `use` and if I call `MyClass::myFunction()` just like that it works.

I also tried to trigger the autoloader manually like suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120779/call-user-func-array-vs-call-user-func) answer comment, but it did not work. Also, `class_exists` returned `false`.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `call_user_func(array($class, $method));`?

Comment: Yes I did, result was the same.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're missing the namespace:

```
$class = '\\MyBundleNamespace\\MyClass';
$method = 'myFunction';
```

Both calls should work:

```
call_user_func("$class::$method");
call_user_func(array($class, $method));
```

Comment: Yeah it worked! I prefer the variable function way so I used: `$namespace = "MyNamespace"; $class = "$namespace\\MyClass"; $method = "myMethod"; $class::$myMethod();`

Comment: Could you please tell me why I had to add the namespace? Is it related to the fact that the whole thing is evaluated runtime?

Comment: Sure. If you don't specify the namespace (or import it with "use") current one is used.

Comment: Well I know that, but the `use MyNameSpace\MyClass;` **was already** in the file...